# Have macro 'return' a value

Tags: c++, macros, return-value

I'm using a macro and I think it works fine -

```
#define CStrNullLastNL(str) {char* nl=strrchr(str,'\n'); if(nl){*nl=0;}}
```

So it works to zero out the last newline in a string, really its used to chop off the linebreak when it gets left on by fgets.

So, I'm wondering if I can "return" a value from the macro, so it can be called like

```
func( CStrNullLastNL( cstr ) ) ;
```

Or will I have to write a function

Comment: You don't have to write either one -- just use `strtok(str, "\n")`. While it's not what `strtok()` was really designed for, it does the job perfectly (in fact, it's one of the few good uses for `strtok()`). In C++ you should just use `std::getline()` instead of `fgets()` though.

Comment: What do you want it to return?

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: Wouldn't that replace the FIRST newline instead of the last one?

Comment: @Fred:`fgets` only reads one line, so the first is also the last (and always the last character in the string, if it's present at all). If you were using in some completely different situation, where you might have more than one, then yes, it would stop at the first.

Comment: If you know the `\n` is either the last character of the string or not present, then you don't need anything fancier than `strlen()`.

Comment: @Jerry: I see what you mean.  I forgot about the `fgets()` part.

Comment: Why a macro rather than a proper function?

Comment: @JesperJuhl At the time, I think I was trying to "optimize" since I read that `inline` is a "hint" to the compiler that might not be used. But you're right, a macro is a naïve choice here. I find macros are great where their unique features need to be used, like token pasting, passing along values of `__LINE__`, `__FILE__`, `__FUNCTION__`, etc

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For a macro to "return a value", the macro itself has to be an expression.  Your macro is a statement block, which cannot evaluate to an expression.

You really ought to write an `inline` function.  It will be just as fast and far more maintainable.

Comment: With compilers nowadays, isn't the inline modifier implicit?

Comment: It depends. 1) Even if it is implicit, it's nice to use it to tell other people reading your code that this function should be inlined. 2) `inline` may suppress the generation of a non-inlined version.  By default, a non-inline version is usually emitted into the object "just in case" code in another object needs to take the address of that function (unary `&`).  Marking it `inline` can also tell the compiler that taking the address of the function should be an error.  If you really want to see what actually comes out, use something like `gcc -S`.

Comment: it's also necessary if you're writing the body of the function in a header file (which may be included by more than one implementation file) - otherwise you get linker errors

Comment: ... The linker errors being caused by the generation of non-inlined versions of the function.  And you have to put the body of the function in the header in order for the compiler to generate inline code in every compile unit that pulls in the header, and the distinction between .h*/.c* files is usually lost by the time the code makes it to the compiler.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: ... A downvote, sans explanation, a week after I last said anything.  Does this happen a lot to other folks?  O_o

Comment: not always macro can be replaced by inline functions ie. when you need the sizeof operator

Comment: If you need `sizeof`, you should write a inline template function.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone: I don't think making code `inline` makes any compiler avoid emitting a non-inline version. Or at least, it shouldn't.

Comment: It depends on what is being inlined. If something does not have external linkage and its address is not taken, then no non-inline version need be created. Further, if something with external linkage is never referenced, code will be generated but the linker is free to drop it. LLVM-style compilers might go even further, not needing the `inline` keyword at all. That said, I have used `inline` several times with `gcc -ffunction-sections` and while I haven't checked the .o files, there are no non-inlined copies in the final, linked object. YMMV, caveat programmer, etc.

Comment: Note that macros which call functions taking constant arguments, are not candidates for conversion to inline functions.

Comment: Which is why it's best to get rid of the macro entirely and use an inline function instead.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone `You really ought to write an inline function. It will be just as fast and far more maintainable.` Well depending on the optimization level, not as fast. As a macro is expanded the compiler can analyze the code in order to potentially remove dead code (for example because of an expression which would be detected at compile‑time to evaluate to false).

Comment: @user2284570 You still come out ahead with an in-line function. Optimizations like dead-code elimination have been the default for decades, and you have to turn them off manually. Heck, modern compilers like llvm even optimize further than that. You don’t have to worry about the function changing behavior because someone passed in an array instead of a pointer or reference. If you turn off optimization, for tracing or debugging purposes, it works like you'd expect while a macro stubbornly refuses to look like a function call you could set a breakpoint on. And you get real type checking.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone in my case, no… Optimizations are run after the preprocessor pass of course. Which means the macro is converted to plain code as if it was written manually directly. Also, the compiler is free to ignore an `inline` keyword if it’s heuristics wrongly make "think" that it would slow down the program.

Answer (score 33):

```
#define CStrNullLastNL(str) ({ \
    char* nl=strrchr(str,'\n');\
    if(nl){*nl=0;} \
    nl; \
})
```

should work.

Edit: ... in GCC.

Comment: When I pasted your proposed macro into VS2008 it didn't compile when used from within a function call argument list.

Comment: @jeffamaphone:
Sure it didn't. The `({  })` construct is a GCC extension.

Comment: A damn useful extension, I might add.

Comment: @jeffamaphone: Sure it's not portable. After all, that's the definition of "extension". :)

Comment: The ({ }) construct does what exactly?  evaluate to the last statement?

Comment: @bobobobo Yes it evaluates the last statement. Keep in mind that both parenthesis() and curly braces{} are mandatory.

Answer (score 6):

Macro's don't return values.  Macros tell the preprocessor to replace whatever is after the `#define` with whatever is after the thing after the `#define`.  The result has to be valid C++.

What you're asking for is how to make the following valid:

```
func( {char* nl=strrchr(str,'\n'); if(nl){*nl=0;}} );
```

I can't think of a good way to turn that into something valid, other than just making it a real function call.  In this case, I'm not sure why a macro would be better than an inline function.  That's seems to be what you're really asking for.

Comment: A good way to turn that into something valid is to use the `({ })` GCC extension. But that, obviously, works only on GCC. Of course, I agree an inline function would be way better.

Answer (score 6):

If you really want to do this, get a compiler that supports C++0x style lambdas:

```
#define CStrNullLastNL(str) [](char *blah) {char* nl=strrchr(blah,'\n'); if(nl){*nl=0;} return blah;}(str)
```

Although since `CStrNullLastNL` is basically a function you should probably rewrite it as a function.

Comment: Very clever, love it. In one particular use case I want a helper function in one library which operates on objects for which it doesn't have definitions. But the definitions would be available in whatever code actually used the helper functions. (eg. Qt with and w/out `gui` module.)  Hiding it behind a macro but still keeping a nicely defined function with proper object types seemed like a good compromise.  `#define qtKeyEventNativeModifiers(qkeyevent)  [](QKeyEvent *event) { return (event->nativeScanCode() & 0xff); }(qkeyevent)`  (with `QKeyEvent` being available only in some builds).

Answer (score 6):

Can you use the comma operator? Simplified example:

```
#define SomeMacro(A) ( DoWork(A), Permute(A) )
```

Here B=SomeMacro(A) "returns" the result of Permute(A) and assigns it to "B".

Comment: Sure you can, but you can't put control-flow statements in an expression.  That's where it gets tricky.

Comment: The ?: operator works fine as control flow in an expression.  I use it all the time.

Comment: What if you need to declare a variable to be able to do the work?

Answer (score 4):

I gave +1 to Mike because he's 100% right, but if you want to implement this as a macro,

```
char *CStrNullLastNL_nl; // "private" global variable
#define nl ::CStrNullLastNL_nl // "locally" redeclare it
#define CStrNullLastNL( str ) ( \
    ( nl = strrchr( str, '\n') ), /* find newline if any */ \
    nl && ( *nl = 0 ), /* if found, null out */ \
    (char*) nl /* cast to rvalue and "return" */ \
OR  nl? str : NULL /* return input or NULL or whatever you like */
)
#undef nl // done with local usage
```

Comment: @Mike: 1. I put "OR" between two alternative lines of code because Oraz suggested different behavior. Note missing comma. 2. Not reentrant. Macros are a bad idea to begin with. 3. I suppose. Put two threads in different source files and make it reentrant, too! All a stupid exercise.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have a strict requirement to use only macro, you can do something like this (real life example):

```
#define Q_XCB_SEND_EVENT_ALIGNED(T) \
    q_xcb_send_event_aligned<T>()

template<typename T> inline
T q_xcb_send_event_aligned()
{
    union {
        T event;
        char padding[32];
    } event;

    memset(&event, 0, sizeof(event));
    return event.event;
}
```

And then use it in your code like this:

```
auto event = Q_XCB_SEND_EVENT_ALIGNED(xcb_unmap_notify_event_t);
```

Answer (score 3):

Returning a value is what inline functions are for.  And quite often, said inline functions are better suited to tasks than macros, which are very dangerous and have no type safetly.

Answer (score 0):

to return value from macro:

```
bool my_function(int a) {
    if (a > 100){return true;}else{ return false; }
}
bool val = my_function(200); if(val){ }else{ }
```

---

```
#define my_macro(ret_val,a){\
    if(a > 100 ) { ret_val = true; } else { ret_val = false; }\
}
bool val; my_macro(val, 200); if(val){ }else{ }
```

Comment: That doesn't count. To return a value means you should be able to use it like this:
`
if( my_macro(200) ){
  do_stuff();
}
`