# Setting bits with macros

Tags: pointers, macros

I am learning MCU programming (using RISC-V). To set the bits for certain functions macros are defined. These use bit addresses. Here is an example macro.

`#define Red_V_enable_output(x) *((uint32_t *) 0x10012008) |= (1<<(x))

It is called using the pin to enable output on i.e.

Red_V_enable_output(5);

What I understand is that the bitwise OR, using the value 5, sets the 5th bit to 1 i.e enable pin 5. What is not clear is why the macro actually sets the value, why does it not return the value stored at the address (after the OR)?

Please explain in detail how the macro functions.

The Macro works, I just don't understand exactly why.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you sure it does not return the value?

Try instead:

```
printf("%x\n", Red_V_enable_output(5));
```

I used:

```
~$ cat macro.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define FOO()  "1"
#define BAR(x, y)  *((uint32_t *) (x)) |= (1<<(y))

int what () {
  5;
}

int huh () {
  return 9;
}

int foo = 5;

int main () {
  printf ("%p\n", &foo); // four bytes

  printf ("or-equals gave: %d\n", BAR(&foo, 1)); // 
  printf("what: %d\n", what());
  printf("With return:\n", huh());
  printf("With format: %d\n", huh());
}
~$ ./macro 
0x563a23cd2030
or-equals gave: 7
what: 0
With return:
With format: 9
```

No output from huh() either, cause I didn't give it the printf a format string.

See also:

[Have macro 'return' a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679182/have-macro-return-a-value)

for how to actually return a value.

Extra details:
If you look at the cast "uint32_t *", the compiler takes the number "0x10012008" and treats it as a pointer to a uint32_t.
In other words a location in memory.  Then there is a * in front of that, so the "|=" doesn't act on the address, but on what it points to.  So what it sets it to, is the result of the or-equals of the value(indicated by the leading star - and read as "pointer to" or "points to") at address "(uint32_t *) 0x10012008" (the hex value is cast as a pointer to four bytes - at that address) with a 1 shifted left by the value passed in: 5.  (0x00100000)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I wasn't clear in the original question. What I gather from your post is that the value is modified in memory - is that correct? 
|
I meant to ask does it modify the value in memory or return the value in the modified form?

Comment: So it would seem it does both.  Just add this line to the end of the short program I called macro.c:  printf("foo is now: %d\n", foo);       This shows that yes, the memory of foo had 101 (base2) changed to 111 (base2)  [ 5 to 7], but it also returns the modified value.    I've always believed in just trying it to see!